# How to read from multiple Async JavaScript generators at the same time

Tags: javascript, generator

I have a code like this:

```js
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function* foo() {
    yield 1;
    await delay(100);
    yield 2;
    await delay(100);
    yield 3;
    await delay(100);
    yield 4;
    await delay(100);
    yield 5;
    await delay(100);
    yield 6;
    await delay(100);
    yield 7;
    await delay(100);
    yield 8;
    await delay(100);
    yield 9;
    await delay(100);
    yield 10;
}

async function* bar() {
    yield 'a';
    await delay(200);
    yield 'b';
    await delay(200);
    yield 'c';
    await delay(200);
    yield 'd';
    await delay(200);
    yield 'e';
}

(async function () {
    for await (const num of foo()) {
        console.log(num);
    }
    for await (const str of bar()) {
        console.log(str);
    }

    await delay(2000);
})();
```

which produce:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
a
b
c
d
e
```

What addjustments I should make, to read from 2 generators at the same time, and get:

```
1
2
a
3
4
b
5
6
c
7
8
d
9
10
e
```

Comment: Because of the `delay` calls, doing that is fairly non-trivial. Are you sure this is an accurate representation of your real situation?

Comment: it is close to I think I have. I get 2 generators as output from libary which run a binary. One generator is with output (lines of texts, each line yielded at a time), and another generator contains information about progress (numbers from 0 to 100).

Of course I want to be able to display progress simultaneously while displaying output.

Comment: Okay, thanks, that's *slightly* different, because the synthetic generators you wrote for the question don't quite have the timing that would result in `1 2 a 3 4 b` etc. But you just want to consume them in parallel (allowing for the single-thread-per-realm aspect of JavaScript). Got it. :-)

Answer (score 4):

In a comment you said:

> I get 2 generators as output from libary which run a binary. One generator is with output (lines of texts, each line yielded at a time), and another generator contains information about progress (numbers from 0 to 100). Of course I want to be able to display progress simultaneously while displaying output.

In that case, loop through the async generators in parallel:¹

```
async function show(g) {
    for await (const value of g) {
        console.log(value);
    }
}
(async function () {
    // Start processing the first one
    const pFoo = show(foo());
    // Start processing the second one
    const pBar = show(bar());
    // Wait until both are done
    await Promise.all([pFoo, pBar]);
})();
```

**But**, note that if you do that with the specific two synthetic generators in your question, the output won't be exactly what you've said you wanted, because `foo` writes `1` **synchronously** before waiting 100ms, and similarly `bar` writes `a` **synchronously** before waiting 200ms, so the results start with `1 a 2 b` and then continue with `3 4 c 5 6 d 7 8 e` and so on. They **are** interleaved as you've said you wanted, just those synthetic ones don't quite have the timing you were expecting when writing the question.

Live Example:

```js
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function* foo() {
    yield 1;
    await delay(100);
    yield 2;
    await delay(100);
    yield 3;
    await delay(100);
    yield 4;
    await delay(100);
    yield 5;
    await delay(100);
    yield 6;
    await delay(100);
    yield 7;
    await delay(100);
    yield 8;
    await delay(100);
    yield 9;
    await delay(100);
    yield 10;
}

async function* bar() {
    yield "a";
    await delay(200);
    yield "b";
    await delay(200);
    yield "c";
    await delay(200);
    yield "d";
    await delay(200);
    yield "e";
}

async function show(g) {
    for await (const value of g) {
        console.log(value);
    }
}
(async function () {
    const pFoo = show(foo());
    const pBar = show(bar());
    await Promise.all([pFoo, pBar]);
})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

¹ "Parallel" in `async` terms. They don't literally run in parallel threads, they interleave (sort of like "cooperative multitasking"). JavaScript restricts its execution semantics to only a single active thread within a given realm ("realm" loosely means global environment and the code in it).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way you can consume them as a single async generator, by using [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) on each iteration:

```js
async function* race(iterable) {
  const generators = [...iterable];
  const next = gen => {
    const promise = gen.next().then(
      ({ done, value }) => ({ done, value, gen, promise }),
    );
    return promise;
  };
  const promises = generators.reduce(
    (set, gen) => set.add(next(gen)), new Set(),
  );

  while (promises.size > 0) {
    const { done, value, gen, promise } = await Promise.race(promises);
    promises.delete(promise);

    if (!done) {
      promises.add(next(gen));
      yield value;
    }
  }
}

(async () => {
  for await (const value of race([foo(), bar()])) {
    console.log(value);
  }
})();

function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function* foo() {
  yield 1;
  await delay(100);
  yield 2;
  await delay(100);
  yield 3;
  await delay(100);
  yield 4;
  await delay(100);
  yield 5;
  await delay(100);
  yield 6;
  await delay(100);
  yield 7;
  await delay(100);
  yield 8;
  await delay(100);
  yield 9;
  await delay(100);
  yield 10;
}

async function* bar() {
  yield 'a';
  await delay(200);
  yield 'b';
  await delay(200);
  yield 'c';
  await delay(200);
  yield 'd';
  await delay(200);
  yield 'e';
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the advantage of this approach?

Comment: @noisy I figure that was self-explanatory, but to be explicit, this creates a single context that receives every fulfilled value as it arives from the original two async generators in parallel. In the other two answers, there are still two contexts that receive values in parallel, but they would require additional coordination if all the values need to be available in a single context.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to TJ's functional approach, you can wrap each loop in an IIFE:

edit note: Originally this answer included promises, hence TJ's comments.

```js
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function* foo() {
    yield 1;
    await delay(100);
    yield 2;
    await delay(100);
    yield 3;
    await delay(100);
    yield 4;
    await delay(100);
    yield 5;
    await delay(100);
    yield 6;
    await delay(100);
    yield 7;
    await delay(100);
    yield 8;
    await delay(100);
    yield 9;
    await delay(100);
    yield 10;
}

async function* bar() {
    yield 'a';
    await delay(200);
    yield 'b';
    await delay(200);
    yield 'c';
    await delay(200);
    yield 'd';
    await delay(200);
    yield 'e';
}

(async function () {
    
    const numPromise = (async () => {
      for await (const num of foo()) {
            console.log(num);
      }
    })();
    
    const strPromise = (async () => {
      for await (const str of bar()){
        console.log(str);
      }
    })();
    
    await Promise.all([numPromise,strPromise])
    console.log('Done!')

      
    await delay(2000);
})();
```

Comment: You're right TJ. I was gonna make some edits, and turn it into mini async IIFE's and take the promise out. Thank you!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder On an unrelated note but about that anti pattern. I was working on a project where at some point in a big async function I needed to wait for click events. For that I used a promise to put `resolve()` in the event handler. Is that a valid approach in your opinion or is there a better way to handle callback and event based async operations.

Comment: It would depend on the specifics of the situation I think. But fundamentally, we do sometimes have to wrap non-promise-enabled APIs into promise wrappers. The antipattern isn't **all** use of `new Promise`, just *unnecessary* use. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the headsup on the Reference Error! I fixed it. I was contemplating that too honestly, but I'll keep it just as a quick visual reference for anyone who can't imagine it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Haha I feel you, and while I was hoping to learn about some magical equivalent to that approach with purely async await, I'm still satisfied. Thanks a lot TJ!

Answer (score -2):

I feasibly do not think that's possible while in JavaScript engine especially using async functions because the interpreter reads in ordered manner, when you have two console.log() functions the first console.log() function is first executed before the other that's why the numbers are printed before the letters.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).